# Pygame: Function polling for REST response with time.sleep delay freezes game window

Tags: python, rest, pygame, wait, sleep

I'm actually programming a multiuser pygame game where the clients are communicating with the Server through REST-Requests. I got a function, where the game has to wait until another player enters his 'queue' on the server, to start a new game. I did this by polling the server with my get-Request (done with Requests) with a time.sleep-delay in between. But this time.sleep causes my game-loop to stop, too and freezes my game window while waiting. But I want to offer the user to leave the game queue during the wait. This isn't possible, because my screen is freezed and turns into the "Leave Queue"-dialog not showing up and the user not being able to click this button or even the 'x' at the top right to leave the queue.

I already tried to start the polling function as a thread, but this does not fix the screen freezing/game loop stopping.

Answer (score 1):

A few key points on how to make this work:

- Handle all your socket I/O in a thread
- Send [Pygame Events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) back to the main loop when socket-things happen
- Don't sleep or delay your main pygame event-loop. Ever.

Here's a Socket-Listener thread example, which posts events back to the main pygame thread. My apologies for the length of the code, but I wanted to answer with something feature-complete.

```
import threading
import pygame
import random
import enum
import socket
import select
import time


### Event types that are sent to the main event loop
class NetworkEvents( enum.IntEnum ):
    EVENT_HANGUP    = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    EVENT_COMMAND   = pygame.USEREVENT + 2


### Socket-listener thread that reads commands from the server
### and does the parsing and posting of commands to the main event-loop
class ConversationHandlerThread( threading.Thread ):
    """ A thread that handles a conversation with a single remote server.
        Accepts commands of 'close', 'red', 'green' or 'blue', and posts messages
        to the main PyGame thread for processing """
    def __init__( self, server_address, server_port ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.server_address = server_address
        self.server_port    = server_port
        self.server_socket  = None
        self.data_buffer    = ''
        self.daemon         = True # exit with parent
        self.done           = False

    def stop( self ):
        self.done = True

    def connect( self ):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
        while True:
            try:  
                self.server_socket.connect( ( self.server_address, self.server_port ) )
                break;
            except:
                print( "Failed to connect %s:%d, will retry" % ( self.server_address, self.server_port ) )
                time.sleep( 12 )

    def run( self ):
        """ Connects to Server, then Loops until the server hangs-up """
        self.connect()

        # Now we're connected, start reading commands
        read_events_on   = [ self.server_socket ]
        while ( not self.done ):
            # Wait for incoming data, or errors, or 0.5 seconds
            (read_list, write_list, except_list) = select.select( read_events_on, [], [], 0.5 )

            if ( len( read_list ) > 0 ):
                # New data arrived, read it
                incoming = self.server_socket.recv( 8192 )
                if ( len(incoming) == 0):
                    # Socket has closed
                    new_event = pygame.event.Event( NetworkEvents.EVENT_HANGUP, { "address" : self.server_address } )
                    pygame.event.post( new_event )
                    self.server_socket.close()
                    self.done = True
                else:
                    # Data has arrived
                    try:
                        new_str = incoming.decode('utf-8')
                        self.data_buffer += new_str
                    except: 
                        pass # don't understand buffer

                    # Parse incoming message (trivial parser, not high quality) 
                    # commands are '\n' separated
                    if (self.data_buffer.find('\n') != -1 ):
                        for command in self.data_buffer.split('\n'):
                            command = line.strip()
                            # client disconnect command
                            if ( command == 'close' ):
                                new_event = pygame.event.Event( NetworkEvents.EVENT_HANGUP, { "address" : self.server_address } )
                                pygame.event.post( new_event )
                                self.server_socket.close()
                                self.done = True

                            # only make events for valid commands
                            elif ( command in ( 'red', 'green', 'blue' ) ):
                                new_event = pygame.event.Event( NetworkEvents.EVENT_COMMAND, { "address" : self.server_address, "message" : command  } )
                                pygame.event.post( new_event )
                        self.data_buffer = ''  # all used-up


### MAIN

# Start the connection-listener thread
thread1 = ConversationHandlerThread( '127.0.0.1', 5555 )
thread1.start()
```

Once the thread is running, events are received in the main loop, just the same as any other PyGame event:

```
# Main paint / update / event loop
done = False
while ( not done ):
    SPRITES.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

        elif ( event.type == NetworkEvents.EVENT_HANGUP ):
            print(" CLIENT DISCONNECTED %s " % ( str(event.address) ) )

        elif ( event.type == NetworkEvents.EVENT_COMMAND ):
            print(" CLIENT MESSAGE FROM %s - %s " % ( str(event.address), event.message ) )
            if ( event.message == 'red' ):
                new_sprite = AlienSprite( RED )
                SPRITES.add( new_sprite )
    # ... etc.
```

If your socket I/O is handled in a thread, and the main event-loop is never sleeping, you should be able to make a nice-flowing program with PyGame.  Keep your network traffic small and concise.

Comment: Hey Kingsley, thank your for your detailed answer. As I have to use REST communication (it's a given requirement). I'm not sure if this approach will work for me. But your tip about using userevents gave me an different idea which I'm going to try. I used them a while ago, but they totally got out of my mind :)